# Dynamically addRange to Google EmbeddedChart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization, google-sheets

I want to dynamically add ranges to a new EmbeddedChartBuilder but I'm getting this error:

"in dashOutput - line: 605, error: InternalError: Cannot find method insertChart($Proxy843)."

Here is code that is not dynamic but works:

```
var tRange = sourceSheet.getRange(12, 1, 4, 2);
var tRange2 = sourceSheet.getRange(12,3,4,2);
var chart2 = destSheet.newChart()
             .setPosition(5,6,5,5)
             .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE)
             .addRange(tRange)
             .addRange(tRange2)
             .build();
destSheet.insertChart(chart2);
```

But this gives me that error.

```
var tRange = sourceSheet.getRange(12, 1, 4, 2);
var tRange2 = sourceSheet.getRange(12,3,4,2);
var chart2 = destSheet.newChart()
             .setPosition(5,6,5,5)
             .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE);
chart2.addRange(tRange);
chart2.addRange(tRange2);
chart2.build();
destSheet.insertChart(chart2);
```

The second example isn't dynamic but if it worked, I would repeat .addRange() inside of a loop.

Any ideas?  What am I missing?  Do you really have to know how many ranges you are going to add at time of chart creation?

Thanks,
Eric B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the [Sheet.newChart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet#newChart) method creates an instance of the [EmbeddedChartBuilder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_embeddedchartbuilder) class, the [EmbeddedChartBuilder.build](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_embeddedchartbuilder#build) method creates an instance of the [EmbeddedChart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_embeddedchart) class and the [Sheet.insertChart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_sheet#insertChart) method requires the `EmbeddedChart` instance. In 1st code the `chart2` variable is instance of the `EmbeddedChart` class and in the 2nd case the `chart2` variable is instance of the `EmbeddedChartBuilder` class. That is why the error takes place. Change the code as following. It should work.

```
var tRange = sourceSheet.getRange(12, 1, 4, 2);
var tRange2 = sourceSheet.getRange(12,3,4,2);
var chart2 = destSheet.newChart()
             .setPosition(5,6,5,5)
             .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.LINE);
chart2.addRange(tRange);
chart2.addRange(tRange2);
destSheet.insertChart(chart2.build());
```

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know why but I figured that .build() gathered everything and prepared chart2 to be inserted.  I didn't realize that .build() returned a different object.  Guess I missed that in the documentation.